# How is it that the size of Ubuntu Core grew so much between 13.10 and 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, 13.10, ubuntu-core

I noticed that the download **size** of Ubuntu Core almost doubled for the amd64 version between release [13.10 `38M`](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/13.10/release/) and [14.04 `63M`](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/14.04/release/).

The untarred "minimal" rootfs file system size did grow from `119M` to `209M`.
<sup>measured using `du -ch ./**/*`</sup>

How does this come?

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu Core for amd64 the number of packages did grow from `103` to `184`. This can be verified in the [ubuntu-core-13.10-core-amd64.manifest](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/13.10/release/ubuntu-core-13.10-core-amd64.manifest) and [ubuntu-core-14.04-core-amd64.manifest](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-core-14.04-core-amd64.manifest).

## 81 New packages

- adduser <- [new dependency of `ifupdown`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/ifupdown)
- apt-utils
- bzip2
- console-setup
- cron
- debconf-i18n
- dh-python
- dmsetup
- eject
- file
- gcc-4.9-base:amd64 <- [new dependency of `libgcc1`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgcc1)
- init-system-helpers
- iputils-ping
- isc-dhcp-client
- isc-dhcp-common
- kbd
- keyboard-configuration
- less
- libapt-inst1.5:amd64
- libarchive-extract-perl
- libbsd0:amd64
- libcap2-bin
- libcgmanager0:amd64 <- [new dependency of `libudev1`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/libudev1)
- libdebconfclient0:amd64 <- [new dependency of `base-passwd`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/base-passwd)
- libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64
- libestr0
- libexpat1:amd64
- libffi6:amd64
- libfribidi0:amd64
- libgcrypt11:amd64
- libgdbm3:amd64
- libgnutls-openssl27:amd64
- libgnutls26:amd64
- libgpg-error0:amd64
- liblocale-gettext-perl
- liblockfile-bin
- liblockfile1:amd64
- liblog-message-simple-perl
- libmagic1:amd64
- libmodule-pluggable-perl
- libmpdec2:amd64
- libnewt0.52:amd64
- libp11-kit0:amd64
- libpam-cap:amd64
- libpod-latex-perl
- libpopt0:amd64
- libpython3-stdlib:amd64
- libpython3.4-minimal:amd64
- libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64
- libsqlite3-0:amd64
- libssl1.0.0:amd64
- libtasn1-6:amd64
- libterm-ui-perl
- libtext-charwidth-perl
- libtext-iconv-perl
- libtext-soundex-perl
- libtext-wrapi18n-perl
- lockfile-progs
- logrotate
- lsb-release
- mime-support
- net-tools
- netbase
- netcat-openbsd
- ntpdate
- perl
- perl-modules
- python3
- python3-minimal
- python3.4
- python3.4-minimal
- resolvconf
- rsyslog
- sudo
- ubuntu-minimal
- ucf
- ureadahead
- vim-common
- vim-tiny
- whiptail
- xkb-data

### ARM architecture

#### Linaro nano

> Provides a very minimum rootfs that's contains a fully function
>   support for apt (the package management system used by Ubuntu). This
>   image only provides console support, and should be used in case you
>   want a fast and small image to develop and verify the kernel and
>   system functionality. — https://wiki.linaro.org/Platform/DevPlatform/Rootfs

Even the minimal rootfs distribution [Linaro nano Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) has `171` packages](http://releases.linaro.org/14.07/ubuntu/trusty-images/nano/linaro-trusty-nano-20140727-680.packages) and is relatively huge with [48MB in download size](http://releases.linaro.org/14.07/ubuntu/trusty-images/nano/) compared to the [`184` packages for Ubuntu Core Trusty (14.04) ARMhf release](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-core-14.04-core-armhf.manifest).

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't answer the why: Why were these packages included? Or, conversely, why were packages like perl, vim-tiny not already present?

Comment: @muru 4 Of the 81 package were new dependencies of packages that were already installed in 13.10. For the remaining 77 packages I can't find any explanation, not in the 14.04 release notes, not in the last years archives of ubuntu developers mailing list, and not on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/). Maybe [Adam Conrad as ubuntu-core images blueprint creator](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/other-o-arm-core-images) can shed some light on this matter.